# SQL: How to select only newest cross entries?

Tags: sql

For my example, i'll write it like this.

I have a table calles maps. There are entries like this (simplyfied):

```
ID,TITLE,MAP,VERSION.
```

Now i insert three maps:

```
INSERT INTO maps VALUES(1,'MAP1','some blob stuff',1);
INSERT INTO maps VALUES(2,'MAP2','some blob stuff',1);
INSERT INTO maps VALUES(3,'MAP1','some blob stuff',2);
```

Now i got one map twice, but two different versions.

How can I now select only the newest maps of each, so then it would only display MAP1 vers 2 and MAP2 vers 1?

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server/MySQL?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. And I just thought this would not work whit GROUP By..? with is actually allowed too, for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT M1.*
FROM maps M1
WHERE M1.version = (SELECT MAX(M2.version) FROM maps M2 WHERE M2.title = M1.title)
```

but I don't see why you need to avoid `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT M1.id, M1.title, M1.map, MAX(M1.version)
FROM maps M1
GROUP BY M1.title
```

EDIT - as pointed out this second query cant guarantee the proper id and map values, stick with the first

Comment: Because the map column value returned is not guaranteed to be the one from the line with MAX(version).

Comment: which query do you think has this issue?

Comment: The second one.  You can get the aggregate values from the group by, but you can't get the "map" column value (the data in this query) from any particular row — it will come from one undefined row.  Many RDBMSes won't allow a GROUP BY query unless all non-aggregated columns are included in the GROUP BY.  MySQL will, but with undefined values in the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: ok i follow, I was a little shaky on that but unfortunately dont have an easy means of testing right now

Comment: But, in MySQL i have to call the result (after mysql_fetch_object in PHP) with $fetched->FIELD, and if yi have two tables, it doesn't work, if I use $fetched->M1.FIELD... how can i solve that?

Comment: they are still called `id`, `field`, etc despite the table identifier in front.  The only time you really have to worry about this is if you have `SELECT T1.id, T2.id`.   You can always `as` to make those fields called whatever you want like `SELECT M1.id as foo`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM maps m1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM maps m2 WHERE m2.title = m1.title AND m2.version > m1.version)
```